# Should there be an absolute value in this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Take the ode $$\dot v +At^{-1}v=0$$

I would assume that we can separate this equation and then jntegrate both aides to get

$$ln|v|=-A\cdot ln|t|+ C$$
Which implies
$$v(t)=C\cdot |t|^{-A}$$

But my teacher completely drops the absolute signs and writes:

$$v(t)=C\cdot t^{-A}$$

Is he wrong or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The equation has a singularity at $t=0$ and cannot be solved across this value. You need to split the resolution in two cases.

- $t>0$: $\log|v|=-A\log t+c_1$ and $v=C_1t^{-A}$;
- $t<0$: $\log|v|=-A\log(-t)+c_2$ and $v=C_2(-t)^{-A}$.

(In both cases, the undeterminate sign of $v$ can be absorbed in the multiplicative constant.)

So both of you are wrong, the solution is made of two pieces with possibly different constants.

Anyway, your teacher's answer is slightly poorer because powers of negative numbers aren't well defined, and your solution is correct in the special case $C_1=C_2$.